# Bass Ad Lib Instruction on conductor score of Britten Simple Symphony

Tags: strings, orchestra, orchestral-strings, double-bass

I'm playing double bass for Britten's Simple Symphony as part of a string orchestra and the conductor score for movement 3 (Sentimental Saraband) has bass 'ad libitum' written at the first bar of the score. The instruction is not on the bass score and recordings seem to have the part played as written.

Although I will likely just play the part as written for the concert I was curious if there is anyone here who knows how this instruction was intended to be interpreted. Obviously it's not an all out 'go wild, do what you want' instruction, but what have been common interpretations, if there are any. Do any Britten scholars know the story and intention?

[image: Britten Simple Symphony Full Score Bar 1-7]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

'Simple Symphony' is a work 'For string orchestra or string quartet'.   The bass part is optional.  This is the meaning of 'ad libitum' here, not 'do your own thing'!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ad lib does usually mean 'play what you want when you want (as long as it fits!)', but here, the more apposite word would be 'optional'. Note that the bass notes pretty well mimic those of the cello, so if there was a double bass available it would be playing an octave copy of the cello's notes - an added luxury, if you like. But the piece will sound just fine if a bassist can't be found. After all, it's a simple piece, arranged for beginners, and where they're concerned, bassists are somewhat rare.

My 'bible' - Oxford Companion to Music - gives four scenarios for 'ad lib'.

1. To vary from a strict rhythm, tempo, etc if so inclined.
2. To include or omit the part of some voice, oor instrument so marked.
3. To include or omit some passage so marked (possibly a cadenza) according to preference.
4. If he (sic) wants a cadenza at the place so marked, to make his own according to his fancy.

The context will show which liberty is in question.

Comment: Not THAT simple a piece!  In fact, quite demanding at times.

Comment: Just to add, 4 weeks in and it is definitely not a simple piece, it has some challenging corners even for good university orchestra. Additionally, the bass is not doubling the cello for a lot of it, there is a separate bass part.